# How to check if each character of a string is in whitelist?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a whitelist of characters that are allowed to be present in a String. Any character that is not found on the whitelist should be replaced by a space (" "). How would I achieve this in Java? Below is the whitelisted charaters.

```
A through Z,
a through z,
0 through 9,
-,!,@,#,$,_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is what you are looking for.

```
String blacklist = "[^A-Za-z0-9-!@#$_]"; //negation of whitelisted characters
str = str.replaceAll(blacklist, " ");   //string to be cleaned up
```

The regex `[^A-Za-z0-9-!@#$_]` targets every character that is not a letter, a number nor any of special characters `-!@#$_` (pay attention to the '^' at the beggining).

If you want only to check if every character in a string is in whitelist you can just simply use [String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
String blacklist = "[^A-Za-z0-9-!@#$_]";
boolean result = str.matches(blacklist);
```

If `result` equals `false`, it means all the characters of `str` are present in whitelist (none of them is "blacklisted").

Comment: The first answer given works fine but I don't think the 2nd answer is good. In fact, the only time I could get it to return true, i.e. flag a bad character, is when I set str = a single bad character.

Comment: I believe the way to go to verify none of the chars in str is blacklisted is:

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(blacklist);

Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

boolean result = m.find();